# Mysterious question migrated 12 times

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, exact-duplicates

I just navigated to SU and saw this:

[image]

The <s>four</s> <s>five</s> **twelve** questions are exactly the same; they have the same answers, comments and the same question, just different ID numbers.

I suppose this isn't really a question, just wondering what may have caused this anomaly.

Comment: I thought it was just me. :S

Comment: Also, the five questions all refer to the same original question ID from Stack Overflow, #6343711.

Comment: It's up to six now. Let's see how far this thing goes. Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also reported on [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95153/same-questions-migrated-multiple-times) affecting Programmers.SE

Comment: Up to 8. Interestingly, all the timestamps are the same, even though they're being added after the fact. This is quite odd.

Comment: It's an error in a scheduled routine that is repeating, we know it's happening...don't feel the need to edit every time with an updated count. (:

Comment: @Rebecca But it's so much fun! `:(`

Comment: 15 occurrences for that

Comment: I'm worried that this would cause a wrongful [post ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this) against [mm1](http://superuser.com/users/85933/mm1) due to the number of closed and deleted questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was an issue with migrations - see:  [Same questions migrated multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95153/same-questions-migrated-multiple-times)

It has been fixed - thanks for reporting

Comment: Thanks for the fix! `:)`